# Trigger jQuery event with plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I know that it's not possible to handle a jQuery event with plain Javascript, but is it possible to trigger a jQuery event with plain Javascript?

Something like:

```
$('body').trigger('myevent', myvar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as JQuery is just a library of JS:

this

```
$('myElem').trigger('myevent');
```

is equivalent to:

```
elem.dispatchEvent(myevent);
```

The question would be: why you need to mix vanilla JS and JQuery?